# CentOS / RedHat DHCP working, static is not

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have installed CentOS 7 minimal install without GUI when I setup network configuration with Webmin web interface or manually editing files with VI it does not work.

When I use e.g. "yum search bind" package it works however "yum install bind" fails and so with any package.

**EDIT:** This is my config:

[image: Config]

**ip addr** command result:

[image: IP ADDR]

Forgot to mention this is inside VmWare Workstation 11 network adapter set to Bridged (dedicated IP) and it was showing in router for a little while then stopped showing there and working.

Comment: Updated config image

Comment: Pls post output of *ip route show*

Answer (score 0):

Under the directory `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, try changing the following parameter in your `ifcfg-eth*X*` file (where `*X*` is your ethernet port #, usually `0`) to:

```
BOOTPROTO=static
```

Presently you have is set to `none`.  NOTE:  `static` may be unsupported so read on...

If that does not work, try adding the following parameter and setting it to NULL:

```
DYNCONFIG=""
```

I'm also curious why your MACADDR is set to NULL ... `MACADDR=""` ?